# Phone jack schematic and datasheet meaning

Tags: telephone, terminal

I am making an Eagle Cad library for this part, and I want to make sure I am making my part correctly. On this datasheet, http://www.switchcraft.com/Drawings/35rapc2av_cd.pdf, I am assuming that:

- "terminal" is the sleeve of the male phone jack connected to ground and corresponds to the big rectangle on the schematic
- "shunt terminal" is connected to the male phone jack tip and corresponds to the triangle shape on the terminal
- "tip spring" corresponds to the mini arrow connection on the schematic

Answer (score 1):

"Tip spring" would be the inverted "V" on the schematic, and "shunt terminal is the downwards-pointing arrow.  "Terminal" would be the body of the mating plug, and "Tip spring" would contact the tip of the plug.

"Shunt terminal" is a switch contact that is normally connected to the Tip Spring, and is disconnected when the plug is inserted in the jack.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic vs physical layout]

If there's any doubt, you can always test with a continuity tester and a test plug.

Comment: Thank you. This removes ambiguity. I do also use my continuity tester, but I don't have this physical part yet.